# How can I know if a given user has an admin account in a window server 2012 machine?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, windows-server-2012

I am required to run a Jenkins job that that is to be executed on a slave machine from the master machine. The job comprises of running some powershell scripts on the  logged slave machine. 
I am using an account to login from master to slave which I suppose, doesn't have the admin rights as the behavior of the script differs when run as an administrator in the machine to that when run in locally on it.

How can I really confirm if the user provided to me has the admin rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell 4.0 and newer, you can use the `#Requires -RunAsAdministrator` comment at the top of the script to prevent the script from running if the current user is not elevated. For earlier PowerShell versions, you can terminate the script if the current user is not elevated using code. For example:

```
$elevated = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] `
  [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
if ( -not $elevated ) {
  throw "This script must be run elevated (Run as administrator)."
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) Will try this out... Anyways, I shall be thankful if you can tell me as how can I remotely run a powershell script in an admin mode on a system when I have logged in as a standard user?

Comment: Like, when I have found that the current user is not elevated and I want to now run a script in administrator mode...

Comment: Just got to read a blog that can help me to run my script in admin mode. @Bill_Stewart, it seems to be an addendum to what you have stated. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script/

Comment: You can't automatically bypass the UAC prompt, if that's what you are asking. (If this were possible, all malware would do it.)

Comment: Yeah, that's true...Anyways, I have asked the devops people to give the admin role to my Jenkins user. I am now able to open in administrator mode now.